# Blue card validity after deregistration

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a blue card from when I worked for a firm in Germany. I came back to India on the 12th of October 2020, after deregistration (Abmeldung) in Germany. But the blue card validity is until December 2024. Now I have another job in Germany. Is it possible to go to Germany once again with this blue card? Or do I have to apply for a visa once again?

Comment: This is an Expatriates question. Generally a residence permit will expire after 6 months absence from Germany or your residence has been abandoned. (The validity of the card is irrelevant) The date you left Germany would then be needed to answer your question correctly.

Comment: I returned back to India on 12th October 2020.

Comment: Then you should react swiftly, reporting a new job opportunity to them. Is it in the same town?

Comment: Did you find the answer somewhere? as I have the same case